# Group in python

Tags: python, export, brian

I would like to use one of the functions of the Brian2 simulation library in python, but I can't figure it out what should I write in its place of 'group'.

the documentations of this function:

```
def export_data(group, variables):
'''
Abstract static export data method with two obligatory parameters.
It should return a copy of the current state variable values. The
returned arrays are copies of the actual arrays that store the state
variable values, therefore changing the values in the returned
dictionary will not affect the state variables.

Parameters
----------
group : `Group`
    Group object.
variables : list of str
    The names of the variables to extract.
'''
```

So far I have found that there is a group class within brian2: [https://brian2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/brian2.groups.group.Group.html?highlight=group][1]

Please help me!

Thanks!
[1]: https://brian2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/brian2.groups.group.Group.html?highlight=group

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is as simple as

```py
import brian2
from brian2 import Group

g = Group()
varlist = []

# I don't know how to use the module itself, so I'll just type the method like it's a global one
export_data(g, varlist)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried but it gives a 'NotImplementedError' so there is sadly a still not developed feature :(

Answer (score 0):

there is no export function into a vector in brian2 however you can get it easily :

```
def export_brian2(brian_obj):
  spike_indices = brian_obj.i
  spike_times = brian_obj.i # time in ms

  return spike_indices, spike_times
```